# Not working handleChange when copy & paste in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on validating an email in React. But it's **not working when copy&paste to input**. When I type by keyboard is working. How can the app validate text even if it's pasted.

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      email: "",
      disabled: true,
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    const { email } = this.state;
    this.setState({ email: e.target.value });
    if (/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[A-Za-z]+$/.test(email)) {
      this.setState({ disabled: false });
    } else {
      this.setState({ disabled: true });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input
        name="email"
        type="email"
        placeholder="Enter your email"
        value={this.state.email}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to initialize the value:

```
value={this.state.email || ''}
```

I'm not sure why onChange is not working for you. You could use onInput instead or both. It might be that you're using IE?

Comment: Hmm, I fixed it but not working validation in pasting.

Comment: Try onInput then.

Comment: I tried `onInput` but it's not working. I don't know why but `onChnage` and `onInput` are not working in pasting.

Comment: Which browser you're trying with?

Comment: Chrome I use it

Comment: Ah, I see the `disabled` attribute is not being used in your input. Use it and it should work fine.

Comment: what was the issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
  handleChange(e) {
    if (/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[A-Za-z]+$/.test(e.target.value)) {
      this.setState({ disabled: false });
    } else {
      this.setState({ disabled: true });
    }
    this.setState({ email: e.target.value });
  }
```

`setState` was not working in same handleChange.